# SOAP Request and Response with ASP.NET using the WSDL URL As Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

Ok, installed Visual Web Developer 2008, Created a Website as ASP.net (C# Language), than added a Service to it via the following URL:  http://ws.idssasp.com/members.asmx?wsdl and after hitting Go, looks like this (I change the namespace to `ServiceMembers`):

[image: ServiceMembers]

Now it looks like this:

[image: SolutionExplorer]

If I than go to Default.aspx.cs file, How do I use this on Page Load?  I want something to be outputted from the Service on Page Load, ofcourse, will need to call something else via a button, but really just need a way to get anything from this service to be outputted...  How to do this?

[image: How to output Service Information for Members?]

Looking here:  http://ws.idssasp.com/members.asmx there are a bunch of methods that resemble the pic above, but how to use them anywhere?  When I try to do `Response.Write(ServiceMembers.GetCategoryListResponse);` if gives error that this is a Type and can not be used in that way.  How do I use anything here?

Also, I will need to pass a `Username` and `Password` into the initial SOAP POST to that URL (which I have), before I can get anything back as a Response, but how?  Looks like I should use `ServiceMembers.AuthorizeHeader` somehow?  But how?  Looking at the Request XML from this page [here](http://ws.idssasp.com/members.asmx?op=GetCategoryList&pn=0) for `GetCategoryList`, has this listed in the XML:

```
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizeHeader xmlns="http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthorizeHeader>
  </soap:Header>
```

But how to do this via code to the server?  Unknown!

I don't see `GetCategoryList` Method as an option for `ServiceMembers` namespace anywhere, but there is `GetCategoryListRequest` Type and `GetCategoryListResponse` Type as options for `ServiceMembers` via the last pic.  How do I invoke Methods of a Service?  How do I use any of this for this step in the process?  I have read so many tutorials on this, but nothing that I've seen explains how to do this without error of some sort, or different situations than mine.

Can anyone start me out with just simple code on outputting anything from this Web Service?  Anything at all?  Everyone is saying to use Visual Web Developer as it will do the Bulk of the work for you, but no one is explaining how to use any Web Service that you install.  Seems that they only explain on how to use Specific things in Web Services, it's like they aren't teaching you to fish in an ocean of fish, but instead setting you up to fail, with a fish in a bucket that you are sure to catch.

What is the next step here?  I didn't create this Web Service, and I don't know how to use it in the ASP.NET Website either.

Comment: See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/). It's more modern than the legacy technology you are using, but you might get the idea. Also, I strongly recommend against ever using web site "projects", as they are strange and do things in a unique way. Many of the questions you might ask could only be answered by someone who knows about the "uniqueness" of a web site "project".

Comment: That example uses a Console Application and has files in it that won't be used in Web Applications.  I need a Web Application specific example here, since it will be using HTTP-POST via the Web, where editing the files that he recommends are not even in those types of Projects for the Web, only for Console.

Comment: It makes no difference at all what kind of application you use. The protocols used are the same, no matter what.

Comment: And, what files are you referring to that are "only in console"? Most likely you have hit what I said - web site projects are unique. Every other kind of application in .NET behaves the same. Even web application projects are like all other project kinds. It is only web site "projects" that are strange like this.

Comment: You do not have a web application. You have a web site project.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that I need a Web Application instead, right?

Comment: That would be my recommendation if you have any choice at all. Everything about a web site "project" is different; they are a mistake made by Microsoft, and given a misleading name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetCategoryList` method is in `MembersSoapClient` class and you need to create an instance of `MembersSoapClient` to use `GetCategoryList`. Try this in your `Page_Load` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthorizeHeader authorizeHeader = new AuthorizeHeader();
    authorizeHeader.UserName = "yourusername";
    authorizeHeader.Password = "yourpassword";

    MembersSoapClient client = new MembersSoapClient();
    Category[] categories = client.GetCategoryList(authorizeHeader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not showing anything at all on that page.  Could it be that there are no categories to show?  Anyway we can test this?

Comment: What do you mean it is not showing anything on the page? Did you successfully call the service? Did it return an empty array of categories?

Comment: @SolomonClosson please try to debug, set a break point at the last line, and see if you get something in `categories` after calling `client.GetCategoryList(authorizeHeader)`.

Comment: How do you know if it connected or not?  The page is blank... when I browse to `Default.aspx` file.

Comment: @ekad - It says:  `categories = null`  How to input a Category into this list to be sure it is working??

Comment: Did you pass the actual UserName and Password? `"yourusername"` and `"yourpassword"` in my answer are just examples, you have to change them.

Comment: And don't forget to press F10 when you reach the break point at the last line.

Comment: Yes, I changed them and I believe it worked cause when I hover over the `authorizeHeader` parameter, it shows the username and password in there correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46800/discussion-between-ekad-and-solomon-closson)

Comment: This actually does work for connecting to the Web Service!  Thank you!  I seem to have another problem now... where it only works when I view the Default.aspx page in my browser via the Visual Web Developer program (right clicking file and select "View in Browser"), but not in localhost where the files are being stored at.  Strange!!!